# Python exception when a Path is not found

Tags: python, exception

I have a scenario where I need to check a path or a directory or a version of any software by writing a Python code.
When a path or a directory or a version of any software is/are not found, could you please suggest me which Exception I can add in the except block of the Python code?

Note for additional information - I went through the Python exception hierarchy but unfortunately, I don't see any exception for PathNotFound and SoftwareVersionNotFound scenarios related error.

Comment: What code do you have right now? You'd use `os.path.isdir(...)` to figure out if `...` exists and is a directory.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError), you could use `OSError` that can handle also I/O failures such as “file not found”.
You can also use another built-in [exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError) like `FileNotFoundError`.

Lastly, you can create your own exceptions, like this:

```py
class SoftwareVersionNotFound(Exception):
    pass
```

and you can use it as you would use a built-in exception.

Comment: Got your point! Thank you @blunova